# Spring Pagination sorting with cases

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a problem with Sorting in Spring. I have an enum class

```
public enum Category {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F;


   private static final List<Category> THRILLER;
   static {
       THRILLER = Arrays.asList(A, F, D);
    }

   private static final List<Category> DRAMA;
   static {
      DRAMA = Arrays.asList(C, E, B);
    }
}
```

The Movie Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Movie {
    ...
    private Category category;
    private Timestamp realizationDate;
    ....
}
```

Now I have a rest endpoint that return movies List. I want to Sort this list according to the following order: Movies they belong to THRILLER should be displayed first. When two movies belong to the same category then this should be sorted by realization date.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/movies")
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Movie>> list(@PageableDefault() Pageable pageable) {
  .......
}
```

I tried it with:

```
@SortDefault.SortDefaults({SortDefault(sort="category", direction=Sort.Direction.ASC), SortDefault(sort="realizationDate", direction=Sort.Direction.ASC)})
```

But this Sort the enum only alphabetically.

I need a possibility to do something like: `Sort.by(Category.THRILLER.contains(movie.getCategory()))`. It is possible that I achieve that with Pageable or should I do it another way?

Comment: For me, your code makes no sense, you have enum which represents category type, and field name as category name, which is list and aggregates other categories? Where is the point?

Comment: I have movie entiy which contains field category. And as described i want to sort movies by they categories and realization date when category is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data directly only supports sorting by simple attributes.
So in order for this to work you need to provide an `isThriller` attribute.

You can do this with the existing object structure by using:

a) a trigger to fill the column in the database

b) use a view to compute the desired value

c) if you use Hibernate you may use the `@Formula` annotation to instruct it to compute the value.

In either case you are hardcoding the categories that make up thrillers in a String or in the database.

If you don't want that you could make `Category` an entity with an `isThriller` attribute which you then can query and sort by in the usual fashion.

Comment: I solved it by using a database view where i added isThriller attribute. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `Sort` in spring pagination sorts fields only in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (same like in SQL, uneless you use some procedural version of SQL like PSQL) so you can't introduce some custom logic of sort.

You have two options:

- introduce custom procedure/function into your DB and call it from code (ugly & bad approach)
- Sort list of movies by playing with lambdas and custom comparators, after fetching it from DB (clean & simpler approach)

Comment: I think the second suggestion wont work since im working with pagination.

Comment: Yes, but you have your own endpoint where you can introduce custom sorting logic.

Comment: Then i must get all movies then sorting then creating page and that will be so heavy because we have lot of movies. The sorting must happen in Database layer